# add a current state to each list item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an unordered list with some items that leads to another div  I show on hover.

**html**

```
<div class="dotdiv">
  <ul>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
  </ul>

   <div class="info-1"></div>
   <div class="info-2"></div>
   <div class="info-3"></div>
</div>
```

**javascript**

```
$(function(){
$('.dotdiv li').hover(function(){
    $('.info-' + $(this).attr('id').replace('li','')).show();
$('.info-' + $(this).attr('id').replace('li','')).css('display', 'block');

},function(){
    $('.info-' + $(this).attr('id').replace('li','')).hide();
$('.info-' + $(this).attr('id').replace('li','')).css('display', 'block');
});
});
```

Right now when I hover over item 1, 2 , ... it is displayed, and when I hover out the item still stays there exactly like i want it to. But now If I go back and try to show any of the items the last one is only visible. So I am guessing that i need to update my script, and make sure that it works regardless of the order of the items you hover over.

**UPDATE**

Here is the jsfiddle http://fiddle.jshell.net/7QmR5/

Comment: That html doesn't match the code you show - the `.dotdiv` element doesn't have any `li` children, and the `li` elements don't have `id` attributes. Where are the elements with the `id` beginning with `info-` that have CSS set on the second line of each function? Could you correct that and perhaps set up a demo at http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Still not working over here - like @nnnnnn said, could you post a JSFiddle [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/VE6wm/) ?

Comment: In the mouseout handler why are you calling `.hide()` and then `css('display','block');` on the same element? `block` would unhide it again. Also that updated html still doesn't have ids so it still can't be the same as your real code...

Comment: @nnnnnn just give me a min i am setting up a jsfiddle for it.

Comment: Take a look at my update...

Comment: Is this version what you are looking for: http://fiddle.jshell.net/7QmR5/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to modify the html:

```
$('#pop li').each(function(i, el){
$(this).hover(
    function(){
       $("[id^='info']").eq(i).show().siblings("[id^='info']").hide();
    },
    function(){
       $("[id^='info']").eq(i).show().siblings("[id^='info']").hide();   
    }
)
```

});

Answer (score 1):

You could format your elements as follows

HTML

```
<li id="1">Item</li>
<div id="info-1"></div>
```

Which allows you to do the following

```
$(".dotdiv > ul > li").hover( function( ) {
    $(".dotdiv > div").hide();
    $("#info-" + $(this).attr("id") ).show();
});
```

Fiddle [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/bruno/DNLjm/3/)

Comment: when you mouse out it disappears... I want a current state added... so whichever item was last hovered over should be displayed

Comment: @DinoExcel Updated my example. Just don't hide the div on hover out.

Comment: @DinoExcel Sorry updated my example so divs are initially hidden

Comment: I really dont understand why you rewrite my entire code, and replace it with something that wont work if you have one additional div containing your > div indicator... Not good solution at all in less words

Comment: @DinoExcel I can only answer the question that was put to me and according to your question my solution worked. If you update your question with the new structure I will be more than happy to change my answer.